# AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52

Tags: websphere

The whole users unable to login to the portal application with below ldap exception noting that no changes recently happened.

com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection DirContext reCreateDirContext(String errorMessage)
                                 com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.WIMSystemException: CWWIM4520E  The 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1\u0000]; Resolved object: 'com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@dd641796'' naming exception occurred during processing.
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.reCreateDirContext(LdapConnection.java:931)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.search(LdapConnection.java:3211)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.checkSearchCache(LdapConnection.java:3091)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.search(LdapConnection.java:3281)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.searchEntities(LdapConnection.java:3502)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapAdapter.login(LdapAdapter.java:3060)
        at

Comment: That indicates invalid credentials. Try running an ldapsearch with the same search and credentials (this runs outside of WebSphere). Check that the user/pass is valid and not expired, as well as the bind DN/bind password.

Comment: I’m able to login by the wpadmin from the ldap but from the websphere console not able to login

Comment: I'm assuming that is the user and there are separate bind credentials? Can you check the wimconfig.xml in <profile>/config/cells/<cell_name>/wim/config/wimconfig.xml. Your repositories are listed here. Make sure the bindDN and bindPassword are good.